# How to utilize a .NET SDK inside Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-functions, nuget

I am trying to figure out how to utilize a .NET SDK into Azure Function.

What I am trying to do is pull data from a third party app called Sage's Intacct thru web service and push data into Azure SQL Server.

This is data flow:
(Sage's Intacct --> Azure Function --> Azure Data Factory --> Azure SQL Server).

I have a .NET Nuget SDK ( https://github.com/Intacct/intacct-sdk-net ), and I am using Visual Studio 2019 on my local machine and trying to publish into Azure Function.

This is [URL](https://developer.intacct.com/tools/sdk-net/) for documentation.

I was able to install their .NET SDK Package inside FunctionApp solution.

[image]

I am trying to modify config file so I could grab data from Sage's Intacct thru web service (Http).

From other discussion thread, I got the tip that I probably need to use "HTTP Triggered Function".

Now, my challenge is, how do I utilize the Nuget package (Intacct.SDK) with Azure Function?

If I open a new solution file, I could see details of this package, but from here, I cannot publish cs file into Azure Function.

[image]

What is approach?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow is a bit confuse, but you should be able to add Sage Intacct using Nuget:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Intacct.SDK/

Then, it will be a dependency of your project which will be deployed together with you Azure Function code.

Comment: Actually, I just found that there is a solution file that has some example of cs files (https://github.com/intacct/intacct-sdk-net-examples). I think I would just use the "Http Triggered function solution", add Sage Intacct SDK as dependency (which I already did) and utilize example cs files to create Function cs files. Now I need to figure out how to make cs file as Function file. I am guessing you just put  [FunctionName("Function2")] after class name.